# Is any form of checkdisk ran on a schedule?

Tags: windows, chkdsk, windows-task-scheduler

One question I see pop-up from time to time is

> How often should Check Disk/Error Checking be ran on my system? Is it necessary as a form of preventative maintenance?

It's gotten me curious as to whether or not any form of Check disk is run on a regular schedule in any iteration of Windows, and, if so, at what iteration did it start?

Comment: CHKDSK can only be performed on an unmounted drive because it requires an unchanging filesystem.  If it's not the system drive, then that drive can be unmounted, and would be inaccessible.  This condition is not conducive to arbitrary scheduling, but rather is best performed under explicit admin control.  The system drive can only be checked prior to booting, and can be scheduled for the next boot.  IIRC Ubuntu Linux performs the equivalent `fsck` operation automatically for old ext2 filesystems every 30-or-so boots.  Journaled filesystems (which includes NTFS) are much more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 will regularly optimize your drives by default. However it appears that a CHKDSK is not included in an optimize; only a defrag.

You can check if a disk optimization is scheduled to run by checking the following location:

1. Open **This PC**, right-click drive C and select **Properties**.
2. Select the **Tools** tab and, under the heading 'Optimize and defragment drive', click **Optimize**.
3. Under 'Schedule optimization', you will see if drive optimization is on and how frequent. Windows 10 defaults to a frequency of **Weekly**.

There is no indication that chkdsk is run on a schedule automatically.
However if the scheduled disk optimization fails, it is a good indication the the CHKDSK utility needs to be run.

[Image: Windows 10 Disk Optimize Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxkmc.png)

Comment: Does optimization include a file system check (CHKDSK) ?

Comment: I was under the impressions that CHKDSK was run as part of the optimization, but I can't find any documentation to confirm this. The closest I can find on forums suggests that if the optimization (defrag) fails, manually run a CHKDSK. So it would indicate otherwise. Clarified response to indicate this.